# angularjs ui-router come back to the current state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular `ui-router` in my application. I have a 2 states, `create-app` and `list-apps`. When i create an app i transition to the state `create-app` with param `id` equal to `null`. The problem is that when i am on state `create-app` i cannot `transitionTo` `create-app`. The use case is that if in the middle of creating an app i want to create another app i have to `transitionTo` `create-app` but since the state is already `create-app` ui-router does not change the state. I know this because i looked for firing of `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` event. None of these fire. But when i am on 'list-apps' or even `create-app` with param `id` not equal to `null`(which is edit app) i am able to come to state `create-app`.

```
$scope.createApp = function() {
       $state.transitionTo('create-app', {id: null});
    };
```

SO i tried this

```
$scope.createApp = function() {

            if ($state.current.name == 'create-app' && $state.params.id == null) {  // when the state is create-app and not list-apps or edit-app
                   $state.current.name = '';    
            }
            $state.transitionTo('create-app', {id: null});

    };
```

In this when the state is `create-app` and the i again try to come to the same state i change the state name to `''` and params to `null` so angular finds the `fromState` and `toState` different . Even this does not work. Is there some way i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$state.reload().](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state) There's a discussion on github about this [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/76).
Use it like this:

```
$state.reload();
```